# gen_tcp:connect will close when using supervisor

Tags: erlang, erlang-supervisor

I have a simple gen_server which connects to a tcp port, when I run gen_server directly:

`erl -noshell  -s ttest start`

it works fine, But when I run:

`erl -noshell -s tt_sup start_link`

the connection will be closed instantly, It will work if I unlink the supervisor:

`erl -noshell -s tt_sup start_shell`

How could I run my simple gen_tcp:connect (gen_server) with supervisor ?

Supervisor :

```
-module(tt_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).
-export([init/1, start_link/0, start_shell/0]).

start_link() ->
    io:format("Supervisor started with PID~p~n", [self()]),
    {ok, Pid} = supervisor:start_link(tt_sup, []),
    io:format("Supervisor PID=~p~n", [Pid]),
    {ok, Pid}.

start_shell() ->
    io:format("Supervisor started with PID~p~n", [self()]),
    {ok, Pid} = supervisor:start_link(tt_sup, []),
    io:format("Supervisor PID=~p~n", [Pid]),
    unlink(Pid),
    {ok, Pid}.

init(_Args) ->
    SupFlags = #{strategy => one_for_one},
    Child = [#{id => ttest, start => {ttest, start, []},
               restart => permanent, shutdown => brutal_kill,
               type => worker, modules => [ttest]}],
    {ok, {SupFlags, Child}}.
```

gen_server:

```
-module(ttest).
-export([start/0,init/1,handle_cast/2,handle_call/3,handle_info/2,terminate/2,connect/1]).
-behaviour(gen_server).



start() ->

       io:format("gen_server start id is ~p~n",[self()]),
       {ok,Pid} = gen_server:start_link({local,ttest},ttest,[],[]),
       io:format("gen_server id is ~p~n",[Pid]),
       connect(Pid),
       {ok,Pid}.



init(_Args) ->
        io:format("init id is ~p~n",[self()]),
        {ok,[]}.       
handle_call({tcp,Socket,Bin},_From,States) ->
        {reply,States,States}.
handle_info({tcp,Socket,Bin},States) ->
        io:format("got info msg"),
        {noreply,States}.

handle_cast({send,Msg},States) ->
        {reply,States}.

connect(I) ->
    io:format("connect id is ~p~n",[self()]),
    {ok,Socket} =gen_tcp:connect("localhost",6000,[binary,{active,true}]),
    gen_tcp:controlling_process(Socket,I).



terminate(shutdown, State) ->
    io:format("terminating"),
    ok.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process that runs the `-s` exits with `normal` when it has no more code to execute. The supervisor receives that signal and since it's from its parent, it exits (regardless of it being `normal`), as explained in [gen_server:terminate/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:terminate-2) (`supervisor`s are `gen_server`s with `trap_exit` active):

> Even if the gen_server process is not part of a supervision tree, this function is called if it receives an 'EXIT' message from its parent. Reason is the same as in the 'EXIT' message.

I haven't tested your code, but if you add a `process_flag(trap_exit, true)` to your `gen_server`, you'll surely replicate this behaviour.

Comment: yes if I add ```process_flag(trap_exit, true)``` to gen_server init, It will be the same, how should I start the supervisor?

Comment: @Geo-7 If you want to create a production-grade project with a proper OTP supervision tree, you should create an application and a release with it, check https://learnyousomeerlang.com/building-otp-applications#why-would-i-want-that and https://learnyousomeerlang.com/release-is-the-word (learnyousomeerlang is a superb reference). If you want to have it running ASAP, just add an `timer:sleep(infinity)` before `tt_sup:start_link` returns